# Let k be a field and let p, q ∈ N be two prime numbers such that p · 1 = q · 1 = 0. Show that p = q.

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory

My current train of though is letting p =/= q then proving that q must be divisible by p, the contradiction then being that q is prime. But I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

Comment: $p,q=0\in k$ shown by multiplying both sides by the inverse of 1.

Comment: What about $(p-q)\cdot 1$ ?

Comment: 0 is not a prime number, so p,q=/=0

Comment: @123454321: You are confusing the statement "$p = 0$ in $k$" with "the integer $p$ is zero". These do not mean the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

If $p \neq q$ then we have $x,y$ such that $xp+yq=1$ since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a Euclidean domain. But then $1 = (xp+yq)1 = 0$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

If you assume $p \neq q$, and let $p > q,$ then $(p-q)\cdot 1 \neq 0$ since $p-q$ is not prime.

But $(p-q)\cdot 1 = p \cdot 1 - q \cdot 1 = 0,$ a contradiction.

Comment: "$p-q$ is not prime": not true. We might have $(p,q) = (5,3)$. Also, just because a number $n$ is not prime, it doesn't follow that $n\cdot 1 \ne 0$.